# Why does shell redirection interact strangely with find

Tags: shell, find, sh

I want to add a license file to the front of every .java file in a *nix directory and any subdirs. I have this solution, which seems to work fine:

```
$ cat muppet-license.txt 
// LICENSE: // Manuh-manuh
$ for file in `find . -iname "*.java"`; do 
     cat muppet-license.txt "$file" > "$file.out"; 
     mv "$file.out" "$file";
done
```

My question is, why does the following find invocation NOT work:

```
find . -iname "*.java" -exec sh -c 'cat muppet-license.txt "$1" > "$1"' -- {} \;
```

This causes the very first file found by find to have the "muppet license" repeatedly added to the front of it - the file seems to continually grow without stopping.

Can someone explain what's causing the difference here is? Is it something to do with the modification of the file called $1 causing find to re-find it as part of the recursive search? Does anyone have any good references to the details of the algorithm that find uses?

Answer (score 3):

You are telling cat to read from the same file as you are writing to:

```
cat muppet-license.txt "$1" > "$1"
```

So cat will read `muppet-license.txt` and write it to `$1`, then read `$1` (which now contains the license) and append the license again to the end of the same file, then continue reading what has been written, and so forth, in an endless loop replicating the license file within `$1` over and over...

Something like this should work:

```
find . -iname "*.java" -exec sh -c 'cat muppet-license.txt "$1" > "$1.out"; mv "$1.out" "$1"' -- {} \;
```

This avoids the endless loop by writing the license and `$1` to a separate file `$1.out` and moving it back to `$1` after writing to it. The difference has nothing to do with find, only with the invocation of sh and cat.

Comment: I get that. That isn't the q I asked. Did you read it properly?

Comment: Either you misunderstood what I (and others) have answered, or you need to edit to clarify your question. Edited my response slightly to make the meaning more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that

```
cat foo $file > $file
```

will do exactly what you tell it to do, which is not always obvious. The first thing the shell does with that command is opens `$file` for writing thus truncating it to zero length. Then `cat` is run, concatenating `foo` and the contents of `$file` which are now a copy of foo into `$file`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with find.  The same behavior occurs if you do:

```
cat muppet-license.txt a.java > a.java
```

and is because cat is re-reading the data it is writing.  The shell opens a.java for writing, truncating it to zero length.  cat then writes the contents of muppet-license.txt into a.java, and then opens a.java (which is now a copy of muppet-license.txt), and writes the first line to the end of the file (the 2nd line).  It then reads the 2nd line and appends it the end (writing line 3), and repeats continuously.

Comment: @kittylyst: What comment?  Are you referring to my answer?  What about my answer do you find confusing?  The shell truncates a.java, discarding all the data in it.  cat then enters an endless loop and never terminates (until your filesystem is full or some other error occurs).